# ngrok not running due to proxy

Tags: http, proxy, tunnel, ngrok

I have ngrok installed on Ubuntu. I want to expose an application at 8080. The machine is behind a corporate proxy. I exported an environment variable http_proxy with the proxy value and tried to run the command:

```
./ngrok http 8080
```

The status remains reconnecting and the error says "Proxy Authorization required".
I have also tried it using a ngrok.yml config file with the proxy value. And specified the path of the file:

```
./ngrok http -config=./ngrok.yml 8080
```

This is how the config file looks:

```
console_ui: true
inspect_db_size: 50000000
log_level: debug
log_format: json
log: /var/log/ngrok.log
http_proxy: "http://username:password@proxyhost.co.in:8080"
tunnels:
  jenkins:
    addr: 8080
    bind_tls: true
    inspect: false
    proto: http
```

Still the error persists. Inspite of specifying the correct proxy, its failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

open CMD. And type this:

```
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be the following entry:

```
authtoken: YOUR_NGROK_TOKEN
```

in the configuration file. Perhaps, due to its absence you get the error.
The token you can find from your ngrok-account, from dashboard.